# Reload factory_girl factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I want that when I make changes in factories, I see them in rails console without restarting all console.

I've found some lines and tested them with a poor understanding of what's going on, [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/FactoryGirl.reload) isn't clear for me.:

```
FactoryGirl.reload
```

I've also tested:

```
> FactoryGirl.factories.clear
> FactoryGirl.find_definitions # also tested FactoryGirl.factories.find_definitions
                               # but NoMethodError is raised
=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Address with ID=277 Torphy Squares
```

Comment: I usually use a mere: `FactoryGirl.reload`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using [Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/). See the diff of changes that solved the problem:

```
# factories/building.rb, address is a string

- address    Faker::Address.street_address
+ address    { Faker::Address.street_address }

# factories/user.rb, email is a string

- email Faker::Internet.email
+ email { Faker::Internet.email }
```

And then `FactoryGirl.reload` works.

Comment: Right - that's a big gotcha with FactoryGirl. In the first case, the Faker::Address is evaluated just once, when the factory is loaded, and then never again. Thus it is a constant. In the second case, the code block is evaluated every time it is used, thus it changes for each time it is used. The second case is almost always what you intended, the first case is just a bunch of exposed sharp spinning blades lying there waiting to hurt someone.

Comment: This answer saved me a ton of time too. Serves me right for not RTFM (see dynamic attributes in their getting started guide).

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `reload!` to reload the console environment but it doesn't reload the factories. Use `FactoryGirl.reload` to reload the Factory definitions. It (re)loads those definitions from the following locations (see the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#defining-factories)):

```
test/factories.rb
spec/factories.rb
test/factories/*.rb
spec/factories/*.rb
```

The other commands you mention are used to clear and load the definitions. `FactoryGirl.factories.clear` clears all loaded Factory definitions, while `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` reloads all definitions from file.

Be sure to use the `factory_girl_rails` gem if your on Rails. When you've for example defined a `factory :user`, you can use it in your console with `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` or `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`. This will return a User instance.

If that doesn't work, please post some more details.

Comment: reload! doesn't work. What do you mean it reloads the factories? For example, does it set the sequences back to square 1?

Comment: `def self.reload
  reset_configuration
  register_default_strategies
  register_default_callbacks
  find_definitions
end`