# Using FactoryGirl to mock a missing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

My application has a built in messaging service, and there are cases I need to handle, where the user has just removed his/her account, but I still need to display the messages in the conversations for the other users, and replace the missing user to avoid app crashes.

I have thought of using FactoryGirl with specific factories for this case.

My pre question would be, is that a good solution ?

Now to my actual problem. In my development environments, my code gets reloaded on every new request. The problem being, the factories are only loaded once when the server starts. Therefore, after the 1st request, the "classes" my factories are linked to are no longer the classes loaded to respond to the new request, and I can get errors like

```
FactoryGirl.create(:my_class).is_a?(MyClass) # => false
```

Whiwh will cause app crashes (at some point in my code I need to test some classes)

How can I reload my factories for those environments that reload some code on each request, or in general avoid this class mismatch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload factory\_girl factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307091/reload-factory-girl-factory)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth thanks for the link. But that doesn't tell me where I should put this reload code ? It needs to be called <= 1 times per request, depending whether I need to Fake something (and therefore to reload factories) or not. I very seldom need to show pages where I need to fake, reloading factories would be overkill ? I actually have found some code that can reload factories on `ActionDispatch::Callbacks.after` callbacks, but it becomes so slow ! Would make sense to only reload them only if I need to Fake...

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question: reload factories just before using them. If it's noticeably slow, though, it might mean that factory_girl is not the right tool in this case. Hard to say whether it's really necessary without seeing a lot more of the design and code.

Comment: I am often calling my faker code several times when I need to fake something. So I would need to store some boolean in a global variable that gets reset after every request served. How can I do that ?

Comment: I'd use a Rails around filter (`around_action`).